# objects that belong to layer, appears outside on parent layer

Tags: kineticjs

I expect that objects outside of layer (by coords **x** and **y**) 
will not show on parent layer, or canvas, but it appears - http://clip2net.com/s/5HbVnf .

According to my link **"777"** text belongs to red layer, 
but appears on green layer, if i set it `Y` coord to `-25` for example.

How to resolve this issue ?

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});

var text_layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x:150,
    y:50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

var red_rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});

var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 5,
    y: -25,
    text: '777',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: 'black'
});

text_layer.add(red_rect);
text_layer.add(text);

stage.add(layer);
stage.add(text_layer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's how the KineticJS Layers work by default.

The good thing is, you can use the `clip` property to solve your problem by clipping the area outside of the `layer`.

Clipping Tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-clipping-functions-with-kineticjs/

> To draw things inside of clipping regions with KineticJS, we can set the clip property of any container, including a group, a layer, or the stage.  Clipping regions are defined by an x, y, width, and height.

```
var text_layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x: 150,
    y: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    clip: [0, 0, 100, 100] //x,y,width,height
});
```

Or you can use the `setClip()` function: check the [docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Layer.html#setClip)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/gtxTN/)